# Show the most senior of subordinate from each manager in employees table

Tags: sql

i have a task to search the most senior of subordinate from each manager and i just have this code

```
select m.first_name, count(e.employee_id), avg(e.salary),
       trunc(avg((sysdate-e.hire_date)/365),0)||' Tahun '||trunc(avg(mod(sysdate-e.hire_date,365)/30),0)||' Bulan' "Rata"
from employees e
  left outer join employees m on(m.employee_id = e.manager_id)
group by m.first_name;
```

in the last column I want to display the most senior, but I don't know how to search it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: It would help if you could include how your database table is structured, the available column names.

Comment: Tag dbms product used. (Lots of product specific functions there...)